# Read DMQ programmatically

Tags: glassfish, openmq

How can I read messages from "mq.sys.dmq" programmatically. 
I use Glassfish 3.1.2.2

When I try:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("mq.sys.dmq");
QueueConnectionFactory connFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
QueueConnection queueConn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();
QueueSession queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession(false,
             Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
QueueReceiver queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
```

I receive:

> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'mq.sys.dmq'

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the Queue in the Glassfish admin GUI.

Go to `JMS Resources` -> `Destination Resources`:

Create a new entry with `mq.sys.dmq` as `Physical Destination Name` and `javax.jms.queue` as `Resource type`

Comment: For automatic deployment or use in integrations tests (Arquillian), it works fine to put the info to "create" that queue in the glassfish-resources-xml, too. Just tested it.